# facebook Page Access Tokens to get user profile

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-access-token

First time touching things about facebook.

Trying to do facebook 3rd provider login.
The developer I worked with is doing it through back end instead of how facebook's tutorial is doing it through frontend.

Right now the login works and able to get the return of

```
accessToken: "EAAaz15rigu"   
userID: "10928"
```

Now trying to get the user profile such as first, last name and avatar.
I searched around and found this documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/#fields

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PSID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

The thing is, there isn't `<PSID>Page Scope ID` and `<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>` provided

So again, I searched for `page access token`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}
```

this is what I see so I entered what is returned from login     `https://graph.facebook.com/10928/accounts?access_token=EAAaz15rigu`

What I see is an empty array though, even if the array is not empty as show in the sample in the documentation.  I still don't see anything that is `<PSID>` that I can use from  my backend to get user profile.

Can someone please give me a hand to walk through this?

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

Comment: Just call `/me?fields=...` with the user access token you have.

Comment: @WizKid so like `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=...` with get?

Comment: If this is a about normal Facebook login on a website, then you are looking in the wrong place to begin with - your first documentation link there, is for the Messenger API: What you are interested in, is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: @CBroe I read the link you gave me, if I didn't get it wrong, it's actually using FB's SDK infront end right?  Is there a way to use it from the backend instead?

Comment: That is just the description of the available API fields. What SDK/library you use to make any requests, is a totally independent issue.